# Obtaining JSON object value from array

Tags: php, json, foreach

Is there a way to get the values of a JSON object member variable from a array without looping the objects? Similar to how call_user_func_array would work but for member variables?

E.g.

```
     array   0 => 
     object(stdClass)[402]
       public 'id' => int 196
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0   1 => 
     object(stdClass)[403]
       public 'id' => int 197
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0   2 => 
     object(stdClass)[404]
       public 'id' => int 3269
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0   3 => 
     object(stdClass)[405]
       public 'id' => int 3334
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0   4 => 
     object(stdClass)[406]
       public 'id' => int 5831
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0   5 => 
     object(stdClass)[379]
       public 'id' => int 6358
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0   6 => 
     object(stdClass)[400]
       public 'id' => int 6592
       public 'creditLimit' => string '0' (length=1)
       public 'state' => int 0
```

In one single call I'm trying to obtain the summation of `creditLimit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass "true" to `json_decode` to get a regular array.

Comment: Damn!!! Perfect :- array_sum(array_pluck('creditLimit', json_decode($this->_getParam('creditLimits'), true)))